# 438 web pages, 7,675 page view per day from organic searches, just wondering how?

Tags: google, domains, pagerank, seo

I am just wondering how this site - indiahowto(dot)com **with just 438 pages** is managing to **achieve 7,675 pageviews per day** with just organic searches.

Note : I believe it is not listed in dmoz or have any backlinks. It is purely based on organic searches.

Please share your knowledge, thoughts and observations on this.

Thanks :)

Comment: Please read the [FAQ](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq): "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page."

Comment: Hmm, Can you please confirm that you are getting other details properly, Avg time on page, bounce rate, exit and unique pageview also. If they all have genuine data then we are also happy on your success. Else, You will have to take care about web page request.

Answer (score 1):

As [evidenced here](http://siteexplorer.search.yahoo.com/uk/search?p=indiahowto.com&bwm=i), they do have some backlinks - though this is unlikely all of them.

Furthermore, the number of pages on a domain has zero direct effect on whether those pages rank. Don't know where you are getting the page view count from, but unless you have access to their server statistics or analytics account then those figures are almost certainly incorrect.